# Tensorflow - Create MLP using TF

Tags: python, tensorflow

**Background:**

I am trying to create a MLP using Tensorflow, my first time using tensorflow. It is a simple NN that will do the xor operation. I have 2 input neurons (for the 1s and 0s) a hidden layer that is 2 neurons wide. One output that will give me a 1 or 0. My activation is a simple sigmoid.

**The Issue**

I am running into an issue with launching the graph. Something I noticed is that when we launch the graph we get all of the batch instead of one at a time. for example I have the following in an array `[[1,0],[0,0],[0,1],[1,1]]`. When I try to start the graph I do the following:

```
x_vals = np.array([[1.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]])
y_vals = np.array([[1.0],[0.0],[1.0],[0.0]])
result = run_nn(x,y)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    results =  sess.run(result, feed_dict={x: x_vals, y:y_vals})
    print results
```

As we can see I feed in x and y into the neural network. Once I do this I need to multiply the weights * outputs (essentially the input [1,0]) and sum them The issue is that I get a mismatch in size between the x values and the weights array:

tf.transpose(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(tf.transpose(l0.weights) , l0.outputs), 1))

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [2,3] vs. [4,3]
     [[Node: Mul_6 = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](transpose_10, concat_12)]]
```

What am I doing wrong here, I understand this is not a perfect implementation. But I want to do a NN step by step

**Here is my full code:**

```
import math
import numpy as np

momentum = 0.5
learning_rate = 2.0

class layer:
    def __init__(self, num_neurons, num_weights, layer_type):#number of weights corresponds to number of neurons in next layer
        self.num_neurons = num_neurons
        self.num_weights = num_weights
        self.layer_type = layer_type
        if layer_type == 'hidden':
            num_neurons = num_neurons+1#account for bias
            self.num_neurons = num_neurons+1
        self.weights = tf.random_normal([num_neurons, num_weights])
        self.outputs = tf.zeros(num_neurons, tf.float32)
        self.sums = tf.zeros(num_neurons, tf.float32)
        self.deltas = tf.zeros(num_neurons, tf.float32)
        self.gradiants = tf.zeros([num_neurons, num_weights], tf.float32)
        self.weight_deltas = tf.zeros_like(self.gradiants)
    def calculate_sums(self, p_layer):
        self.sums = tf.transpose(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(tf.transpose(p_layer.weights) , p_layer.outputs), 1))
        return self.sums
    def calculate_outputs(self, p_layer):
        if self.layer_type == 'hidden':
            self.outputs = tf.concat([sigmoid(self.sums, False), tf.constant([1.0])], 0)
        else:
            self.outputs = sigmoid(self.sums, False)
        return self.outputs
    def calculate_deltas(self, n_layer = None, y=None):
        if self.layer_type == 'hidden':
            self.deltas = sigmoid(self.sums, True) * n_layer.deltas * self.weights[:-1,0]
        else:#output delta
            E = self.outputs[:self.num_neurons]-y
            #print 'error: {}'.format(E)
            self.deltas = -E* sigmoid(self.sums, True)
        return self.deltas
    def calculate_gradiants(self, n_layer):
        shape = (tf.shape(self.outputs)[0], 1)
        self.gradiants += tf.reshape(self.outputs, shape=shape) * tf.transpose(n_layer.deltas)#we add the gradiants for every batch completion then update, dont want to update every time
        return self.gradiants
    def update_weights(self):
        self.weight_deltas = self.gradiants*learning_rate + momentum * self.weight_deltas
        self.weights += self.weight_deltas
#        for i in range(len(self.gradiants)):
#            for j in range(len(self.gradiants[0])):
#                self.weight_deltas[i,j] = weight_change(self.gradiants[i,j], self.weight_deltas[i,j])
#                self.weights[i,j] += self.weight_deltas[i,j]


def sigmoid(x, derivative = False):
    if derivative == True:
        return (1.0/(1+tf.exp(-x))) * (1.0 - (1.0/(1+tf.exp(-x))))
    return 1.0/(1+tf.exp(-x))
#the output delta is just E*f'i, essentially the error * the derivative of the activation function
def weight_change(g, p_w_delta):#gradiant, previous weight delta
    return learning_rate*g + momentum * p_w_delta

def run_nn(x_val, y_val):
    l0.outputs = tf.concat([x_val, tf.ones(shape=(tf.shape(x_val)[0],1))], 1)
    print 'set output'
    #forward pass
#    l1.calculate_sums(l0)
#    print 'l1 calc sum'
#    l1.calculate_outputs(l0)
#    print 'l1 calc output'

#    ol.calculate_sums(l1)
#    print 'ol calc sum'
#    ol.calculate_outputs(l1)
#    print 'ol calc output'
#    #backwards pass
#    ol.calculate_deltas(y=y_val)
#    print 'ol calc deltas'
#    l1.calculate_deltas(ol)
#    print 'l1 calc deltas'
#    l1.calculate_gradiants(ol)
#    print 'l1 calc gradiants'
#    l0.calculate_gradiants(l1)
#    print 'l0 calc gradiants'
#    #we dont want to update the weights every time, just after we have gone through every batch/minibatch
#    l1.update_weights()
#    print 'l1 update weights'
#    l0.update_weights()
#    print 'l0 uipdate weights'
#    l1.gradiants = tf.zeros_like(l1.gradiants)
#    print 'l1 zero gradiants'
#    l0.gradiants = tf.zeros_like(l0.gradiants)
#    print 'l0 zero gradiants'
#    #test
#    print 'run test'
#    l0.outputs = tf.concat([x, tf.constant([1.0])], 0 )
#    #forward pass
#    l1.calculate_sums(l0)
#    l1.calculate_outputs(l0)
#    
#    ol.calculate_sums(l1)
#    ol.calculate_outputs(l1)
#    print 'DONE'
    return tf.transpose(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(tf.transpose(l0.weights) , l0.outputs), 1))



l0 = layer(2,2,'hidden')#input
l1 = layer(2,1,'hidden')#hidden
ol = layer(1,0,'output')#output
x_vals = np.array([[1.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]])
y_vals = np.array([[1.0],[0.0],[1.0],[0.0]])


# initialize variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
x = tf.placeholder('float', None)
y = tf.placeholder('float', None)
result = run_nn(x,y)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    results =  sess.run(result, feed_dict={x: x_vals, y:y_vals})
    print results
```

**Here is some equivalent code in pure python/numpy**

```
import math
import numpy as np

momentum = 0.5
learning_rate = 2.0

class layer:
    def __init__(self, num_neurons, num_weights, layer_type):#number of weights corresponds to number of neurons in next layer
        self.layer_type = layer_type
        if layer_type == 'hidden':
            num_neurons = num_neurons+1#account for bias
        self.weights = np.random.rand(num_neurons,num_weights)
        self.outputs = np.zeros(shape=(1,num_neurons))
        self.sums = np.zeros(shape=(1,num_neurons))
        self.deltas = np.zeros(shape=(1,num_neurons)).T
        self.gradiants = np.zeros(shape=(num_neurons,num_weights))
        self.weight_deltas = np.zeros_like(self.gradiants)
    def calculate_sums(self, p_layer):
        self.sums = np.array([(sum(p_layer.weights * p_layer.outputs))]).T
        return self.sums;
    def calculate_outputs(self, p_layer):
        if self.layer_type == 'hidden':
            self.outputs = np.concatenate((np.array([[sigmoid(X, False)] for X in self.sums]), np.array([[1.0]])))
        else:
            self.outputs = np.array([[sigmoid(X, False)] for X in self.sums])
        return self.outputs
    def calculate_deltas(self, n_layer = None):
        if self.layer_type == 'hidden':
            self.deltas = np.array([[sigmoid(X, True)] for X in self.sums]) * n_layer.deltas * self.weights[:-1]
        else:#output delta
            E = self.outputs-y
            #print 'error: {}'.format(E)
            self.deltas = -E* sigmoid(self.sums, True)
        return self.deltas
    def calculate_gradiants(self, n_layer):
        self.gradiants += self.outputs * n_layer.deltas.T#we add the gradiants for every batch completion then update, dont want to update every time
        return self.gradiants
    def update_weights(self):
        for i in range(len(self.gradiants)):
            for j in range(len(self.gradiants[0])):
                self.weight_deltas[i,j] = weight_change(self.gradiants[i,j], self.weight_deltas[i,j])
                self.weights[i,j] += self.weight_deltas[i,j]


def sigmoid(x, derivative = False):
    if derivative == True:
        return (1.0/(1+math.exp(-x))) * (1.0 - (1.0/(1+math.exp(-x))))
    return 1.0/(1+math.exp(-x))
#the output delta is just E*f'i, essentially the error * the derivative of the activation function
def weight_change(g, p_w_delta):#gradiant, previous weight delta
    return learning_rate*g + momentum * p_w_delta


input_layer = layer(3,2, 'hidden')
hidden_layer1 = layer(2,1, 'hidden')
output_layer = layer(1,0, 'output')

x_vals = []
y_vals = []
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        for k in range(2):
            x_vals.append(np.array([[float(i)],[float(j)],[float(k)]]))
            y_vals.append(np.array([float(i ^ j ^ k)]))

#x_vals = [np.array([[1.0], [0.0]]), np.array([[0.0], [0.0]]), np.array([[0.0], [1.0]]),np.array([[1.0], [1.0]])]
#y_vals = np.array([[1.0],[0.0],[1.0],[0.0]])
#input_layer.weights = np.array([[-0.06782947598673161,0.9487814395569221],[0.22341077197888182,0.461587116462548], [-0.4635107399577998, 0.09750161997450091]])
#hidden_layer1.weights = np.array([[-0.22791948943117624],[0.581714099641357], [0.7792991203673414]])

Error = []
for n in range(10000):
    for x, y in zip(x_vals, y_vals):
        input_layer.outputs = np.concatenate((x, np.array([[1.0]])))
        #forward pass
        hidden_layer1.calculate_sums(input_layer)
        hidden_layer1.calculate_outputs(input_layer)

        output_layer.calculate_sums(hidden_layer1)
        output_layer.calculate_outputs(hidden_layer1)
        Error.append(-(output_layer.outputs-y))
        #backwards pass
        output_layer.calculate_deltas()
        hidden_layer1.calculate_deltas(output_layer)

        hidden_layer1.calculate_gradiants(output_layer)
        input_layer.calculate_gradiants(hidden_layer1)
    if n % 1000 == 0:
        print 'Epoch #{}; error: {}'.format(n, sum(Error)/len(Error))
    Error = []
    #we dont want to update the weights every time, just after we have gone through every batch/minibatch
    hidden_layer1.update_weights()
    input_layer.update_weights()
    hidden_layer1.gradiants.fill(0.0)
    input_layer.gradiants.fill(0.0)


#test
for x, y in zip(x_vals, y_vals):
    input_layer.outputs = np.concatenate((x, np.array([[1.0]])))
    #forward pass
    hidden_layer1.calculate_sums(input_layer)
    hidden_layer1.calculate_outputs(input_layer)

    output_layer.calculate_sums(hidden_layer1)
    output_layer.calculate_outputs(hidden_layer1)
    print 'Y_hat: {}, Y: {}'.format(round(float(output_layer.outputs), 3), float(y))
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: self.weights needs to be a matrix. There's a weight for each pair of (input, neuron)

Comment: It is an array where the rows are the neurons and the columns are the synapses connecting a neuron to the next layer

Comment: Sorry, my comment was unclear. What are you expecting: return tf.transpose(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(tf.transpose(l0.weights) , l0.outputs), 1))
to do?

Comment: I'm also not sure I understand what you're trying to do with the np implementation. In particular, it looks like you're doing the hadamard product with your weight matrix

Comment: Well in my original implementation I could pass in each x individually so [1,0] then [0,0] etc. When I run the session it passes all of the ex's at once so it gives a mismatch

Comment: You can pass each input individually in tf, too. Are you basically looking for someone to show you an example of how to use tensorflow to solve xor or are you looking for help debugging your implementation above?

Comment: I see I can pass each x val to tf but is that how I am supposed to send it into tf? Sorry I am on mobile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149762/discussion-between-ryan-stout-and-kevin).